# Why is this Ruby code printing 345?

Tags: ruby

```
i=0
loop do
  i += 1
  next if i < 3
  print i
  break if i > 4
end
```

produces 345 which doesn't makes sense because when i reaches 3, then the `next` expression should be evaluated, going again to the loop. The logical thing is to print only 4. Why does this code work the way it does?

Comment: Does writing if statements backwards like that flip the < operator around too????

Comment: I think you are confusing `<` and `<=`.

Comment: When `i == 3` the next statment is not executed as i is not smaller than 3, it is equal.
When `i == 5` then `i > 4` thus the loop will break, but the print statement is before the break, thus 5 is also printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will trace this code on the piece of paper you will see:

- when `i == 0` then: is `0 < 3`? yes => `next`
- when `i == 1` then: is `1 < 3`? yes => `next`
- when `i == 2` then: is `2 < 3`? yes => `next`
- when `i == 3` then: is `3 < 3`? no => `print 3`; is `3 > 4` no
- when `i == 4` then: is `4 < 3`? no => `print 4`; is `4 > 4` no
- when `i == 5` then: is `5 < 3`? no => `print 5`; is `5 > 4` yes => `break`